# eclipse indigo missing installed plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I installed PDT, ADT and some plug-in, yesterday. Today morning, after updating from help->check for updates, I lost all of the installed plug-in. There are "Generals" and "CVS" are left at New Project wizard.

I checked at help->Install new software, the install wizard display, all of the plug-in which I installed are already installed.

What happen? How can I recover the installed plug-in?

============================================================================

Update

This is error log

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.help.base 4 0 2013-05-08 17:01:56.363
!MESSAGE Problem occurred during indexing of documentation.
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid format: 
at org.osgi.framework.Version.<init>(Version.java:150)
at org.eclipse.help.internal.search.SearchIndex.isLuceneCompatible(SearchIndex.java:721)
at org.eclipse.help.internal.search.PluginIndex.isCompatible(PluginIndex.java:152)
at org.eclipse.help.internal.search.PluginIndex.resolve(PluginIndex.java:83)
at org.eclipse.help.internal.search.PluginIndex.getPaths(PluginIndex.java:231)
at org.eclipse.help.internal.search.PrebuiltIndexes.trim(PrebuiltIndexes.java:46)
at org.eclipse.help.internal.search.PrebuiltIndexes.getIndexes(PrebuiltIndexes.java:54)
at org.eclipse.help.internal.search.IndexingOperation.mergeIndexes(IndexingOperation.java:544)
at org.eclipse.help.internal.search.IndexingOperation.addNewDocuments(IndexingOperation.java:152)
at org.eclipse.help.internal.search.IndexingOperation.execute(IndexingOperation.java:106)
at org.eclipse.help.internal.search.LocalSearchManager.updateIndex(LocalSearchManager.java:671)
at org.eclipse.help.internal.search.LocalSearchManager.ensureIndexUpdated(LocalSearchManager.java:645)
at org.eclipse.help.internal.search.LocalSearchManager.search(LocalSearchManager.java:590)
at org.eclipse.help.internal.search.SearchManager.searchLocal(SearchManager.java:103)
at org.eclipse.help.internal.search.SearchManager.search(SearchManager.java:94)
at org.eclipse.help.internal.search.SearchProgressMonitor$2.run(SearchProgressMonitor.java:162)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
at org.osgi.framework.Version.<init>(Version.java:127)
... 16 more
```

Comment: Can you find those plug-ins in dialog opened via 'About' - 'Eclipse' - 'Installation Details'?

Comment: yes I found them at About->Eclipse->Installation Details.

Comment: Ok. All of your plug-ins installation are not removed. But the configuration file of eclipse(<eclipse loc>/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info) is broken. You can check error log to see what's wrong.

Comment: I found the log file. but I don't know how to do?

Comment: Now Java development is return back. but PDT and ADT are still missing. How can I recover them?

Comment: You can unzip your eclipse into a new folder. Then run 'import'-'install'-'existing installation' to install previous installed plug-ins into new eclipse instance.

Comment: Now, I'm installing fresh eclipse. I removed eclipse using the software center and then manually deleted /etc/eclipse.ini, (~/workspace) and .eclipse.

Comment: The recommend way of using Eclipse is that downloading zipped package from eclipse.org, then extract it to somewhere you can write. There are lots of known issues when installing Eclipse into read-only folder.